# Cluster analysis using networkx in python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, networkx

I am trying to perform a cluster analysis for rating scale data, visualized as a network, though I am new to networkx and haven't been able to find many sources on how pre-existing data should be structured, rather than just manually generating nodes and edges with a random dataset. I have multiple observations for different rating scale questions and would like to see how their responses cluster. Here is a sample of my data:

```
Item            Rating
Happy             1
Depressed         3
Anxious           4
Irritated         2
Confused          0
Happy             1
Depressed         5
Anxious           3
Irritated         4
Confused          1
Happy             0
Depressed         4
Anxious           4
Irritated         3
Confused          1
```

Essentially, I'd like to see how these symptoms cluster (by having a node for each of these five items, as well as edges between them all, and if possible, adjustable diameter for each node to represent rating severity). Any feedback on data restructuring or helpful resources for network analysis would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use pandas and turn your observation data into a dataframe.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly (algorithmically/mathematically) you want to do with the data. Do you have an example, e.g. a plot in a paper where someone else did a similar thing? I do not see why you need `networkx`, which is a library for analysing graphs, e.g. finding the shortest/fastest/cheapest connection in public transport, where your input data consists of nodes and edges e.g. bus lines network with prices, distances, travel time...

Comment: `scikit-learn` might be a better choice for your clustering: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: Regarding data restructuring, you may better work with the pivot table of your data, where you use your `Item` values as columns and add an observation number as index.

Comment: What would constitute an edge in this case?